# Searching Texts between (single/double quotes) in Word Document

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I am trying to get a list of data present in (single/double quotes)

**The input data is:**

> Ravi asked Raj "How are You?" and  'Where have you been'. Raj replied
>   "Iam fine Ravi, 'How are you' and 'how did you know this person?'"

**Expecting Output is:**

- How are you
- Where have you been
- Iam fine Ravi, 'How are you' and 'how did you know this person?'

(Boundary quotes need to be considered and it should have single/double quote character embedded inside)

Please advice on RegExp for this in Word VBA.

I am trying below Code but no success:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim mystring As RegExp
    Dim mydata As MatchCollection

    Set mystring = New RegExp
    mystring.Pattern = "\s("".*"")\s"
    mystring.Global = True
    Set mydata = mystring.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range)


    For Each wrd In mydata
        MsgBox wrd
    Next wrd

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```regex
".+?"|'.+?'
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/C7oqzT/1).

However, this includes the single/double quotes in the matches, which doesn't seem to be your expected output. You can remove them using VBA though.

A complete VBA example:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim re As RegExp
    Dim matches As MatchCollection
    Dim m As Match

    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = """.+?""|'.+?'"
    re.Global = True
    Set matches = re.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range)

    For Each m In matches
        'MsgBox m           ' With quotes.
        Dim parsed As String
        parsed = Mid$(m, 2, Len(m) - 2)
        MsgBox parsed       ' Without quotes.
    Next m
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This one seems to work:

```
(?:'|").*(?:'|")
```

or

```
((?:'|").*(?:'|"))
```

if you need a group.

Here's the demo: link

It works, because `*` is a greedy quantifier, so you don't have to know what kind of quote is in the end. * will take as much as possible.

Comment: Since this is for Word, you need to consider smart quotes - both single and double. You should also provide for unmatched single quotes when used as apostrophes - including those that follow a terminating s, as in *He bought John Stevens' tractor*, for example.